# Is kruskall wallis appropriate here?

Tags: panel-data, kruskal-wallis-test, aggregation

I have collected campaign finance data about donations individuals have made to 3 groups (A, B, C) between 2015 and 2020.  Each donor has only donated to one group but some donors have donated multiple years. I am trying to compare the aggregate donation size across the 3 groups between 2015-2020. I plan to use Kruskal Wallis as my data does not meet the assumptions needed for one-way anova.

Would it be appropriate to sum the donations each member has made first and then perform the Kruskal Wallis test?

Edit: My null hypothesis is: There is no difference in the median donation size per donor between 2015-2020 among the 3 groups.

Comment: What does "Each donor has only made a group" mean? How does a donor "make" a group? Please clarify.

Comment: Oh sorry, i meant each donor only made a donation to one group

Comment: To answer your question, that depends on the question you want answered. If it relates to donors as individuals, then you aggregate. If it relates to size of each donation as an independent event, then you don't. If you want both, then you do both.

Comment: what would be your hypothesis here

Comment: @prashanth I have updated my question with my hypothesis

Comment: In general, Kruskal-Wallis is not a test of medians.  You could test for medians with, e.g. Mood's median test.

Comment: I wonder about summing the donations for each individual across years.  On the one hand, it eliminates the complication of having multiple observations for the same individual.  On the other hand, it might not represent what you want to measure.  If a person donates $500 in 2015 and $500 in 2016, is more useful in your case to call this a single observation of $1000 or two observations of $500 ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico Would it be better to just not associate the donation with a donor? Im not too sure which method is better.